# Add rows from Parse CloudCode

Tags: javascript, android, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am using parse cloudCode. I want to add Rows in class using cloudCode .

```
Parse.Cloud.define("OtpRequest", function(request, response) {

    var phone = request.params.phone ;
    var otp = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10000) + 1); 
    var table = Parse.Object.extend("OtpTable");
    var otpVal = new table();

    otpVal.set("mobile",phone);
    otpVal.set("otp",otp);
    otpVal.set("timeStamp","123456");

    otpVal.save(null, {
        success:function(otpVal) {
        },
        error:function(error) {
        }
    });
}
```

This function is not working for me .

Comment: Inspect the log https://parse.com/apps/<your_app_name>/cloud_code/log/error , possibly do some logging yourself. Looks like you do not set success or error on the response callback, making the call fail. The object should however get saved as far as I can tell from a brief look.

Comment: *Not working* is a nonsense. It doesn't work at all or it produces a result different from your expectations. In both cases you have to describe it (error message(s) or different result). Check StackOverflow's help first, please. Focus on [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but also other [help topics](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) would be useful.